# Random number in Actionscript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, math, actionscript, random

I've been following a tutorial written for Actionscript 2, and have successfully converted it to AS 3, however on the second to last part I'm stuck.

The tutorial here (http://www.cleverpig.com/tutorials/whackapig/whack.htm step 8) has the following piece of code:

```
if (_currentframe==1) {
    // randomly choose whether or not to play
    if (random(100)>97) {
      // should we tease or popup?
      if (random(3)<1) {
        this.gotoAndPlay ("popup");
      } else {
        this.gotoAndPlay (1);
      }
    }
  }
```

it is meant to add some randomness to the character's movement. After some googling I created this code in AS 3 hoping it would work.

```
if (currentFrame==1) {
    // randomly choose whether or not to play
    if(Math.floor(Math.random()*99)-97) {
      // should we tease or popup?
      if (Math.floor(Math.random() *3)-1)
   ) {
        this.gotoAndPlay ("popup");
      } else {
        this.gotoAndPlay (1);
      }
    }
  }
```

When I run the program with this code the character's entire animation plays once (down, halfway up, up, hit). It is supposed to only play the first 3 frames, and repeat this.

EDIT:

```
function random (n:int ) : int {
    return Math.floor (Math.random() * n);
}

if (currentFrame==1) {
    // randomly choose whether or not to play
    if(random(100)): 97 {
      // should we tease or popup?
      if (random(3)): 1
      {
        this.gotoAndPlay ("popup");
      } else {
        this.gotoAndPlay (1);
      }
    }
  }
```

Symbol 'hole', Layer 'Actionscript', Frame 1, Line 10   1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before colon.
Symbol 'hole', Layer 'Actionscript', Frame 1, Line 10   1008: Attribute is invalid.
Symbol 'hole', Layer 'Actionscript', Frame 1, Line 12   1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before colon.
Symbol 'hole', Layer 'Actionscript', Frame 1, Line 13   1008: Attribute is invalid.
Symbol 'hole', Layer 'Actionscript', Frame 1, Line 15   1083: Syntax error: else is unexpected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd give a -1 to the writer of the original tutorial, putting a numeric random expression in a a conditional like that.

To determine the outcome of a conditional's expression, it is always evaluated as a Boolean. If you put a Number/int in there, it will be false only if its value is 0(.0). In all other cases (including negative numbers) it will evaluate to true.

Yes, you can make an easier random() function by following @weltraumpirat's answer, but I'd rather recommend you take the random() function out of the conditional and wrap it in a chance() method of sorts. For example:

```
function feelingLucky(ratio:Number):Boolean {
    return Math.random() <= ratio;
}
```

Then calling this method will give you a better x out of y syntax like:

```
if (feelingLucky(97/99)) {
    // you're lucky.
} else {
    // not so lucky.
}
```

Or your other conditional, `feelingLucky(1/3)`. Or try a winning streak with `feelingLucky(100/100)`.

Good luck :)

P.S. Your recent edit fails because of the colons and numeral :97 after the if statements. They shouldn't be there.

Comment: That was it! I just made the changes and they work great now. Thank you very much for taking the time to point out the flaws in the original code, and presenting this alternative.

Comment: @Eric-Paul: You are mistaken: In the original tutorial, the first conditional evaluated to true if the random number was *greater than* 97, so it would be true in 2 out of 100 times, which is exactly what the author intended it to do.

Comment: @weltraumpirat oops, you're right. I assumed both comparing signs were pointing left. Took out that part, but I still stand for the random-in-conditional statement. Cheers.

Comment: @Eric-Paul: I just noticed something curious happening. I have many mc's on stage that start off in sync, and as time goes by the randomness starts and increases randomness.

Comment: @Casey sounds like a new issue to me. Probably has to do with the play head passing by the frame that has this script on it. Any details?

Comment: I solved it. turned out creating 2 more layers ( 3 inn total, front, middle, back) and dividing up the mc instances over these 3 layers worked. Was an interesting example of chaos. the mc's started off perfectly in sync, then over time they became totally random.

Answer (score 3):

You can just easily implement your own random() function and keep the rest of the code exactly the same:

```
function random (n:int ) : int {
    return Math.floor (Math.random() * n);
}
```

Comment: @weltraumpirat. Your formula introduces a bias. The correct formula is `Math.floor( Math.random() * n)` (this excludes n from the possible results). You could also get rid of Math.floor if you are returning positive ints as truncating decimals has the same effect in practice as flooring a positive real number.

Comment: You are right, I was expecting Math.random() to return 0 <= n <= 1, but I checked the documentation, and it's actually 0 <= n < 1.   I have changed my answer to reflect that.  Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @weltraumpirat. No problem. +1 for posting the correct answer by the way.

Comment: @weltraumpirat Thanks. I'm not using it correctly though as I'm getting 5 compile errors. Please see Edit. Thanks.

Comment: The colons : in your if statements are wrong.  Like I said: Keep the original code, the > and < are just fine!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason for changing the more/less operators to a minus operator ?
It seems the if blocks will execute for everything except 0.

The format is

`if (condition)` where condition evaluates to true,false.

I believe your expression is being converted to the boolean type. 
Example

`if (random(100)>97)`
is 99 > 97 => Yes ( Condition evaluates to true )
is 96 > 97 => No ( Condition evaluates to false )

`if (random(100)-97)`
99 - 97 = 2
2 represented as a boolean is true ( Condition evaluates to true  )
97 - 97 = 0
0 represented as a boolean is false ( Condition evaluates to false )

Comment: Hmmm.. Could you elaborate a little Philippe? I'm sort of understanding what you're saying.

Comment: @Casey You first edit to your code was perfectly fine, you were just using a minus instead of the more or less operators provided in the tutorial. So every time the if block was resulting in true for the wrong reasons.